# unknown error on webservice + android java

Tags: java, android, web-services

unexpected error when i try to retrieve the data from my webservice

here is my webservice:
[image: webservice]

here is my android code, i want the result where msgFrom = 1:

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/selectDB";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "selectDB";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://localhost:2998/WebService1.asmx";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("");
        alert.setMessage("Welcome Back,");

        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
        input.setHint("key in password to proceed");
        alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          Editable value = input.getText();

          try
          {
          SoapObject Request = new SoapObject (NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
          Request.addProperty("msgFrom", "1");

          SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

          soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
          soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

          AndroidHttpTransport aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            SoapObject resultString = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();          

            String addon = "";
            for(int i =0; i<resultString.getPropertyCount(); i++)
            {                            
                SoapObject array = (SoapObject) resultString .getProperty(i);
                addon = (addon + array.getProperty(0).toString());        
            }

            alert2.setMessage(addon.toString());
            alert2.show();         
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              alert2.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            alert2.show();
          }
        }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
              android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
              System.exit(1);
          }
        });
    }
```

besides that, i also added internet permission inside my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

here is the logcat:
[image]

when i press the OK button, the apps is force close. not even throw an exception error message. what did i missed?  the sample i used here is 'localhost', but i face the same error too after i uploaded the webservices to my server.

Comment: show your log cat errors...

Comment: @MayurR.Amipara, log cat uploaded

Comment: now saw your MAinActivity.java file's line no. 59

Comment: line 59 is: aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);

Comment: **private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/selectDB";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "selectDB";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://localhost:2998/WebService1.asmx";**  check this.. rest code found ok

Answer (score 0):

KSoap2 library is not in your APK.

If you use Eclipse, right click on your project, select "Java build Path", check ksoap2 jar is in tab "Libraries" and in tab "Order & export", Ksoap2 lib must be present and checked.

Comment: @user3431239 Is it useful ? do you need more info ?

Comment: ksoap2-android-full-2.1.2.jar is already checked. the path is under the project's libs folder

Comment: There's a JAR that contains KSOAP2 lib + all dependencies : "ksoap2-android-assembly-3.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar". You could find it in this wiki : https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse . URL to download it is http://ksoap2-android.googlecode.com/svn/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/3.4.0/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar . Did you include dependencies or just KSOAP lib ?

Comment: @user3431239, Is it useful ?

Comment: sorry for late reply, i have all the required files, and my code has no probolem. after hours of troubleshotting, end up the code needed to put inside the AsyncTask to make it works. Thanks though!